# How to flat nested arrays in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections which I aggregate together using the `$lookup`.

After the aggregation my `$project` results look like that-

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('123456789123345678912345'),
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2',
  key3: [
    ['val1', 'val2'],
    ['val1', 'val3'],
    ['val2', 'val4']
  ]
}
```

I would like to flat and merge all the nested arrays under `key3`, or in other words to get the following result-

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('123456789123345678912345'),
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2',
  key3: ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']
}
```

> **Note:** the `key3` is imported from the lookup collection which I merge into the original document, which contains `key1` and `key2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `key3`, set initial value as empty array
- `$setUnion` to get unique value from inivialValue of reduce and current array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      key3: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$key3",
          initialValue: [],
          in: { $setUnion: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d7HyMqAW6PA)